# Existe alguma forma de fazer o Git ignorar modificações referente a espaços ou quebra de linhas?

Tags: git

Eu tenho mania de refatoração. Se eu vejo algo faltando ou com excesso de quebra de linha, a primeira coisa que eu faço é corrigir.

Eu estou usando o Visual Studio Code num projeto e utilizo o GIT para fazer controle de versão. Esses arquivos que geralmente dou uma quebra de linha ou espaço pra corrigir alguma formatação acaba enchendo a aba de notificação de modificações no projeto.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que o GIT ignore mudanças insignificantes como quebra de linhas ou adição de espaços (que não estejam entre um caractere ou outro, mas espaço em branco).

Quero dizer, quero o GIT desconsidere modificações como essas na hora de listar arquivos para o commit com `git status`.

**Atualização:**

Tem um ser abençoado que trabalha no mesmo projeto que eu que adora usar 2 espaços, enquanto eu gosto de usar 4 espaços por tabulação.

Queria saber se tem como ignorar isso também pelo GIT.

Comment: Sim, era só isso que eu queria dizer :P

Comment: @Maniero quer que adicione "Como fazer isso"? kkkkkk

Comment: Você não quer que os arquivos em questão sejam listados quando você usa `git status` mas quer que eles façam parte do `commit`? Não sei se há alguma maneira de fazer isso... Enquanto minha sugestão nao funciona para todo mundo mas meu time está  usando ferramentas como [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/blob/master/README.md) no pipeline do Jenkins. Depois de fazer merge de uma PR o Jenkins faz mais um commit para formatar o código. Funciona bem apesar de tirar algum controle fino dos devs.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly exemplo: se eu der aquele `git commit -am` que pega os arquivos, gostaria que ignora-se os que tivessem whitespace

Comment: Só como opinião mesmo: penso eu que espaço ou tabulações são caracteres, edições no Git não necessariamente irão para releases e afins, então penso que uma organização de código, tipo: *hoje uso 3 espaços para barra, mas acho 4 quatro fica melhor*, é uma edição valida é algo que pode ser compartilhado entre todos desenvolvedores, até mesmo mudar algo de `if(){` para `if () {`. Eu noto muito as pessoas se preocupando com o historico do Git, mas penso que qualquer ação minima pode ser resolvida e compartilhada. Então pra concluir:

Comment: Sobre os caracteres, mesmo que minimo é interessante que compartilhe para evitar problemas com o "DIFF"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, no `git status` vão aparecer apenas seus arquivos modificados, respeitando seu espaçamento. Não entendi como apareceria o espaçamento do seu colega neste caso. Não está falando de fazer um merge com conflito de espaçamento e "ignorar" isto no `git status`?

Answer (score 4):

> Quero dizer, quero o GIT desconsidere modificações como essas na hora de listar arquivos para o commit com git status.

Entendo que gostaria deste comportamento após fazer algum tipo de merge com uma branch no qual a padronização de espaços usada é diferente da sua.

Embora seja possível fazer este "git status" ignorando as diferenças de espaço, usando um `git diff` (exemplo não testado: `git diff -w | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace`), a resolução do seu problema começa no momento do merge das branches.

Infelizmente não é possível simplesmente ignorar os espaços do arquivo. Um arquivo com 2 espaços é diferente de um arquivo com 4 espaços dentro do git, pois eles geram hashs diferentes. Quando o git vê esta situação em um merge, resta a ele tentar fazer o merge ou mostrar o problema (em forma de conflito).

Contudo, você pode fazer com que ele resolva este merge para você automaticamente, "ignorando" este problema dos espaços. Veja que neste caso você não está realmente ignorando, está apenas dizendo ao git o que fazer neste caso.

Para isto, no momento do merge, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262473/2387977) a flag `-Xignore-space-change`:

```
git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-change
```

O `-Xignore-space-change` aqui é explicado da seguinte maneira, pela [documentação](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), em como ele afeta seu merge:

- Se a versão dele somente introduz mudanças de espaços na linha, sua versão é usada.
- Se a versão sua introduz mudanças de espaços mas a versão dele inclui uma quantidade substancial de mudanças, a versão dele é usada.
- De outra forma, o merge segue normalmente.

## Por fim

No mais, se seu amigo gosta de 2 espaços e você de 4 espaços, e vocês não conseguem chegar em um acordo, vocês podem considerar uma mudança para tabulamento por tab, daí cada um de vocês escolhe o tamanho do tab pela IDE, resolvendo melhor esta questão de como preferem visualizar o código.

Comment: Eu espero que um dia todo mundo use TABS =p

Answer (score 1):

Acesso o aquivo `~/.gitconfig`

Adicionando o alias abaixo

```
[alias]
    addse=!sh -c 'git diff -U0 -w --no-color "$@" | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace --unidiff-zero' -
```

sempre que for `add`  utilize

```
 git addse seuarquivo.txt
```

Documentação de como criar alias https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases

Comment: Oopa, vou ter que testar isso!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta no Stack Overflow em inglês neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428451/9596960).

Abaixo a tradução.

> Parece que você precisa de mais controle e padronização do processo de desenvolvimento. Aquele que comete alterações deve ser a mesma pessoa que modifica os arquivos. Ou pelo menos o committer deve saber exatamente o que mudou.
>
> Examine cuidadosamente a saída do `git diff` e use o flag`-w` para ignorar os espaços. Há também opções para mostrar diferenças dentro de uma linha. Veja * Diferenças dentro de uma linha * abaixo.
>
> Note que você não será capaz de dizer ao git para pular as mudanças de espaço ao confirmar. Eu sugiro usar GitX (eu prefiro o fork "brotherbard"), que permite que você descarte interativamente pedaços antes de cometer.
>
> Use mensagens descritivas ao confirmar. Por exemplo, se um arquivo foi dividido, diga isso. Faça seus commits pequenos. Se você se encontrar escrevendo longas mensagens de commit, divida o commit em partes menores. Dessa forma, quando você examinar os logs muito tempo depois, fará mais sentido o que mudou.
>
> ** Diferenças dentro de uma linha **
>
> O Git tem alguma habilidade para mostrar diferenças de "palavras" em uma única linha. A maneira mais simples é apenas usar o `git diff --color-words`.
>
> No entanto, eu gosto de personalizar o significado de uma "palavra" usando a configuração `diff.wordRegex`. Também gosto do formato `plain`-diff porque mostra mais claramente onde estão as diferenças (insere parênteses em torno das alterações além de usar cores).
>
> Comando:
>
> ```
>     git diff --word-diff=plain
> ```
>
> junto com isso na minha configuração:
>
> ```
> [diff]
>        wordRegex = [[:alnum:]_]+|[^[:alnum:]_[:space:]]+
> ```
>
> Este regex trata estes como "palavras":
>
> - sequências consecutivas de alfanuméricos e sublinhados
> - sequências consecutivas de não-alfanuméricos, não sublinhados e não-espaços (bom para detectar operadores)
>
> Você deve ter uma versão recente do `git` para usar`wordRegex`. Veja sua página man `git-config` para ver se a opção está listada.
>
> **ATUALIZAR**
>
> Se você usa o `git mv` para renomear um arquivo (o que é preferível usar outra ferramenta ou o sistema operacional para renomear), você pode ver git detectando a renomeação. Eu recomendo altamente cometer uma renomeação independentemente de qualquer edição no conteúdo do arquivo. Isso porque o git não armazena o fato de que você renomeou - ele usa uma heurística baseada em quanto o arquivo foi alterado para adivinhar se era o mesmo arquivo. Quanto menos você alterá-lo durante a renomeação, melhor.
>
> Se você alterou ligeiramente o conteúdo do arquivo, você pode usar o parâmetro `-C` para o`git diff` e `git log` para tentar mais difícil detectar cópias e renomear. Adicione uma porcentagem (por exemplo, "-C75%") para tornar o git mais favorável às diferenças. O percentual representa a similaridade do conteúdo para ser considerado uma correspondência.

Espero ter ajudado.